# Unable to handle Float:left property

Tags: css, html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <table style="float:left;margin-left:20px;width:120px">
            <tr><td style="background-color:#EBEBF5;">Profile Info >> </td></tr>
            <tr><td>Entertainment</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Sports & Fun</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Add More </td></tr>
        </table>
        <table style="width:200px">
            <tr><td>info</td><td>Education</td><td>Work</td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Looks like these when browser window is maximized

```
 Profile Info >>   info Education   Work
 Entertainment
 Sports & Fun
 Add More
```

Then I minimized my browser window smaller and smaller to the peak,now it looks like these

```
     Profile Info >>
     Entertainment
     Sports & Fun
     Add More
 info   Education   Work
```

The info,Education and work are going back to bottom of add more why? why width property its not working when i use float:left? how do i handle when i use float:left property?

Comment: In your previous question, you said you're "learning html from internet". To get off to a good start, don't use `<table>`s at all. Forget about `<table>`. The only time you should use `<table>` is when you have actual tabular data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's happening because you're floating the whole table, and your Add More row is part of the main table.  If there's not enough space for them both to fit, the 2nd table will wrap below as you see there.  If you don't want it to wrap then you need to wrap everything in a `div` that has a `min-width` set on it.

```
<div style="min-width: 400px;">
<!--INSERT YOUR TABLES HERE -->
</div>
```